# Извлечь аргумент из Action<T>

Tags: c#

Пишу метод поиска по фильтру. 
Фильтр представлен в виде отдельного класса.  
Хочется иметь возможность не просто скормить экземпляр фильтра, но и пользоваться следующими конструкциями:

```
public static SearchResult GetByFilter(string searchString)
{
    return GetByFilter(f =>
    {
        f.SearchString = searchString;
        f.Score = 7;
        f.Page = 2;
    });
}
```

Чтобы оно заработало, как я понял, в качестве аргумента должен выступать `Action<FilterClass>`, но вот как потом извлекать этот объект фильтра для использования в методе я не нашёл.

```
public static SearchResult GetByFilter(Action<FilterClass> filter)
{
    //Вот тут надо как-то получить тот самый объект, 
    //который мы изменяем в предыдущем примере,
    //чтобы получить строку для url запроса,
    //которую формирует класс фильтра на основе своих свойств.
}
```

Может я вообще не туда забрёл и мне нужен другой тип аргумента? Подскажите как описать класс, чтобы работали подобного рода конструкции.

Вот в качестве примера обычная реализация этого метода:

```
public static SearchResult GetByFilter(FilterClass filter)
{
    return Api.Get<SearchResult>("/search/" + filter.buildQuery());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static SearchResult GetByFilter(Action<FilterClass> filter)
{
    FilterClass filterParams = new FilterClass();
    filter(filterParams);
    // в этой точке у вас будет измененный filterParams
    return Api.Get<SearchResult>("/search/" + filterParams.buildQuery());
}
```

Comment: `filter(filterParams);` - когда уже увидел эту конструкцию всё вдруг стало очевидным. хех.. Спасибо)

Answer (score 0):

Не очень понятно, где создается ваш `FilterClass`, но как пример

```
public static SearchResult GetByFilter(string searchString)
{
    return GetByFilter(() =>
    {
        var f = new FilterClass();
        f.SearchString = searchString;
        f.Score = 7;
        f.Page = 2;
        return f;
    });
}


public static SearchResult GetByFilter(Func<FilterClass> factory)
{
    return Api.Get<SearchResult>("/search/" + factory().buildQuery());
}
```